# MVC post метод с данными с двух форм

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть одна форма на которой расположены checkbox,количество заранее не известно, формируется таблица динамически.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="@item.Id"/>
```

После того как пользователь выбрал необходимые записи и нажал на кнопку вызывается модальное окно в котором нужно выбрать необходимое значение (4 варианта), и после нажатия на кнопке расположенной на модальном окне вызывается post метод. Проблема в том что не могу понять как передать значения id с первой формы в него.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов несколько. вот некоторые из них:

1. передать значения выбранных checkbox'ов в модальное окно (get-параметром, на js) и запомнить их в hidden поле.
2. вернуть выбранный в модальном окне вариант в родительское окно, заполнить hidden поле и сделать пост.
3. сформировать ajax-запрос "ручками", собрав всю необходимую информацию

Comment: а если я заранее не знаю количество полей и как можно js передать в get?

Comment: @e1s, Скорее всего вы будете используете одну из js-библиотек (например  jQuery), c помощью которой вы значительно облегчите себе задачу. 
Если вы пойдете этим путем, вам будет полезно почитать о селекторах. Боюсь я не смогу охватить такую обширную тему в комментариях )

Comment: а второй вариант

Comment: второй вариант схож с первым. Вам необходимо подписаться на событие нажатья кнопки (валидации) модального окна. При этом отменить механизм отправки формы, если таковой уже написан. Далее, с помощью JS узнать какой из 4х вариантов был помечен как "checked", найти нужное поле на родительской форме и записать туда значение. Ну и инициировать отправку родительской формы ). Вашему вопросу, скорее всего, необходимо добавить метку "javascript"

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь оказаться не правым, но меня поправят знающие люди.
У Вас есть два диалоговых окна, что предполагает наличие двух HTML-форм. К формам нужно добавить обработчик на событие `submit`, в котором отменить поведение по-умолчанию, чтоб форма не отправлялась на сервер. Добавляем обработчик на первую форму в котором сериализируем данные формы и сохраняем в переменную. Добавляем обработчик ко второй форме в котором поностью формируем запрос и отсылаем его серверу. Сериализацию форм можно можно выполнять с помощью [jQuery.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), но он мало подходит для ASP. Я использую jQuery аддон [serializeToJSON](https://github.com/raphaelm22/jquery.serializeToJSON).